# jQuery - Prevent too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I trying to submit a form but I get the error "too much recursion" in console.

Here is my code if someone can help

ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form-contact').on('submit',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax('formContact.php', {
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {

                $('#form-contact').each(function(){
                    this.reset();
                });

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `$('#formcontact')`, and why would there be more than one ?

Comment: adeneo ups my bad I have edited :)

Comment: Doesn't really look like anything is wrong, as far as I know `reset` doesn't trigger a submit, so there shouldn't be any recursion from that code ?

Comment: Is the `form-contact` created dynamically? If it is the case, you should change your `on` to `live` or `delegate`

Comment: I have posted the form. And does not work...

Answer (score 0):

adeneo I don't think so, I will pass here the code

form:

```
         <form role="form" action="<?=$base_url?>/contactus.php" method="POST" id="form-contact">
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" placeholder="Assunto">
                <textarea type="text" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem" maxlength="755"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-cont" value="Enviar">
            <input type="hidden" name="subFormContact" value="true">
        </form>
```

formcontact.php

```
      if($_POST["subFormContact"] == true){

            $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["nome"]);
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["email"]);
            $assunto = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["assunto"]);
            $mensagem = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["mensagem"]);
            $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $query_contactus = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM clientes_contact WHERE email = '{$email}'");
            if(($results = mysqli_num_rows($query_contactus) > 0)){


            }else{

                if(($_POST["nome"] == "") || ($_POST["assunto"] == "") || ($_POST["email"] == "") || ($_POST["mensagem"] == "")){


                }else{

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes_contact (nome,email,assunto,mensagem,data)
                            VALUES ('{$nome}','{$email}','{$assunto}','{$mensagem}','{$data}')";


                    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                        $mail = new PHPMailer;

                        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
                        $mail->isSMTP();
                        $mail->Host = 'localhost';
                        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
                        $mail->Username = '';
                        $mail->Password = '';
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

                        $mail->From = $_SESSION["email"];
                        $mail->FromName = $_SESSION["empresa"];
                        $mail->addAddress($_SESSION["email"]);

                        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
                        $mail->isHTML(true);

                        $mail->Subject = 'Admin - Mensagem cliente';
                        $mail->Body    = '<img src="'.$base_template_url.'/logo.png" alt="'.$_SESSION["empresa"].'" height="200" width="200">
                                            <h2>Ervanária Longa Vida</h2>';


                        if(!$mail->send()){
                            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                            exit;
                        }



                    }else{


                    }
                }

                mysqli_close($con);
            }

        }
```